# Magento set moq in product in particular category using observer

Tags: module, price

i want to set moq if user open same product in category A.

for that i used below modules

```
<catalog_product_load_after>
            <observers>
                <setcustomprice>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Module_Customgroup_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>loadaftercatalog</method>
                </setcustomprice>
            </observers>
</catalog_product_load_after>
```

and loadaftercatalog function

```
public function loadaftercatalog(Varien_Event_Observer $event) {
        $product = $event->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $originalprice = $product->getPrice();
        $customprice = 2*$pricetoadd->getPrice();
        $product->setPrice($customprice);

   }
```

give error and does not work can i set moq here so if by default show price of two

Comment: Use `catalog_product_load_before` event. And let me know. If there is error you facing post it here as well

Comment: can u what what to do set moq to 2

Comment: Check my answer